# Using Pandas in Jupyer Lab how can I modify the value of a column in a data frame form a float 2379.77 to a currency value $2379.77?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am working on an assignment and I am trying to display one of the column's values in my data frame as currency $. When doing all the calculations the data displayed on a float but I want to style it to a currency value as it's referring to Total Revenue.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me out with this one. I am attaching my code. I attached a screenshot of the summary table data returned.

```
# I created variables to hold the values to later create the summary table with them. I needed to go back and look at the decimal places that were used in the solution. To be able to match the solution format I decided to use the method round()
ItemCount = df["Item Name"].nunique()
AveragePrice = round(df["Price"].mean(),2)
PurchasedNumber = df["Purchase ID"].count()
Revenue = round(df["Price"].sum(),2)

#After I created the variables I need to store them in a summary table like so:
SummaryTable = pd.DataFrame([{"Number of Unique Items": ItemCount, "Average Price": AveragePrice, "Number of Purchases": PurchasedNumber, "Total Revenue": Revenue}])
SummaryTable
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SummaryTable.loc[:, "Total Revenue"] = SummaryTable["Total Revenue"].map(lambda x: '$' + str(x))
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response! I tried to place it under the SummaryTable before the print statement and it ran but had the same output (Attaching code). It might be that I am not properly inputting the code can you help me take a look, please? Thank you in advance.
SummaryTable = pd.DataFrame([{"Number of Unique Items": ItemCount, "Average Price": AveragePrice, "Number of Purchases": PurchasedNumber, "Total Revenue": Revenue}])

SummaryTable["Total Revenue"].map(lambda x: '$' + str(x))

SummaryTable

Comment: I edited my answer. Let me know how it works.

Comment: It's displaying an incompatible indexer with series. I changed the index to [4], but it still shows the same error. Again thank you so much for helping me with this

Comment: You're very welcome. How about now? I updated my answer.

Comment: YES YES YES!!!! Thank you so much! 
If it's not too much to ask could you walk me through the code? I really want to learn. Here is what I understand from the code: You referenced the df  and sed the loc method to identified the "Total Revenue" column to change its formatting, but I am a little lost with this portion of the code map(lambda x: '$' + str(x)). I can always look in other places what it means if you don't have time. Once again THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Please also give it an upvote if it's possible :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help. `map` method acts on the Series. As an argument, it can apply a function on the each value inside that `series`. As instance, in your dataframe, in `SummaryTable["Total Revenue"]` series goes for values and apply that `lambda` function on each value. In fact, `x` in the lambda function would be each value in the series. For example, first value in the series is `2379.77`, which is a float number. Lambda function change it first to string using `str` function, and then concatenate a `$` to the start of it. I hope it's clear now.

Comment: This is very helpful! Thank you so much!!